# webpack. Как собрать все файлы в один модуль?

Tags: javascript, webpack

При сборке каждый файл собирается в один отдельный модуль. Возможно ли с помощью webpack собрать все в один модуль или вообще без модулей? Просто конкатенировать и минифицировать код в файл.

Конфиг:

```
module.exports = {
entry: entryFileList,
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/web/js',
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: "[name]"
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()      
],

resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: __dirname + "/application/front/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.js"
    },
    extentions: ['', '.js']
}};
```

Структура папок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да можно без проблем. покажите свой конфиг и структуру папок с файлами.

Comment: @DmitryZaharov, ссылки могут служить только дополнением. Все, что относится к вопросу должно быть в самом вопросе!

Comment: @DmitryZaharov, к тому же, приводить листинг кода картинкой - совсем за гранью добра и зла.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример, будьте добры адаптировать его в свой проект сами, если он подходит конечно.

```js
'use strict';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/frontend',

  entry: {
    app: './app'
  },

  output: {
    path:     __dirname + '/public/js',
    publicPath: '/js/',  //   /js/app.js
    filename: "[name].js"
  },

  watch: NODE_ENV == 'development',

  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions:         ['', '.js']
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    moduleTemplates:    ['*-loader', '*'],
    extensions:         ['', '.js']
  }

};


if (NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  module.exports.plugins.push(
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          // don't show unreachable variables etc
          warnings:     false,
          drop_console: true,
          unsafe:       true
        }
      })
  );
}
```

Это код файла ***webpack.config.js*** он из папки ***frontend*** модули копирует в ***public***

Структура папок:

[image: структура]

Дело в том что если ваш код подключает библиотеки или другие зависимости его нужно правильно собрать.

В моём случае это работает. Вот остальные файлы:

***server.js:***

```js
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('./public');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
  if (!/\./.test(request.url)) {
    request.url = '/';
  }
  file.serve(request, response);
}).listen(3000);
```

***frontend/app.js:***

```js
"use strict";

document.getElementById('loginButton').onclick = function() {

  // ======== Способ 1 (require.ensure) ==
  require.ensure([], function(require) {
    let login = require('./login');

    login();
  }, 'auth');

};

document.getElementById('logoutButton').onclick = function() {

  // ======== Способ 1 (require.ensure) ==
  require.ensure([], function(require) {
    let logout = require('./logout');

    logout();
  }, 'auth');

};
```

***frontend/login.js:***

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function() {
  alert("login");
};
```

***frontend/logout.js:***

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function() {
  alert("logout");
};
```

Все возможные варианты подключения зависимостей можно посмотреть здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack - источник.

Comment: К сожалению этот метод не подходит. Он так же оборачивает код каждого файла в свой скоуп. Нужно что бы сборка производилась как в gulp или grunt. Тупо конкатенация и минификация.

Comment: @DmitryZaharov, А почему бы не использовать Gulp или Grunt? Персональный скоуп для каждого файла -- это фича, а не баг

Comment: Хотелось перевести проект на webpack. Но как оказалось он кроме модульного js ни на что не годится. Печально(

Comment: может он тогда: https://github.com/iliakan/gulp-screencast/tree/master/12-organize-final

Comment: webpack - это сборщик МОДУЛЕЙ и используется исключительно для этого.
Посмотрите в сторону rollupjs